# Hard time understanding this while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm have some trouble understanding this while loop, the results of it is "TT", however for me what make sense if it printed out "TP". Can anyone help me out? I'll be showing why I think it should print "TP", and need an explaination why it prints "TT" (which is correct).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char txt[] = "ETERNITTPLATENE-OG-TAKPAPPEN-BLE-KASTET";

void funk(char* t1, char* t2, int n)
{
    while (t1 < t2) { ++t1; t2 -= n; } cout << *t1 << *t2;
}

int main() {
    funk(txt, txt + 27, 3); cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

So first time it it runs func(E, N, 3) so we get
`E < N` which is true, therefore it makes E to T and N to P (as 27-3 is 24, and in that array `P` is in the 24th).

So then we get `T < P`, which is false therefore it should stop the while loop and display `TP`, which it doesn't. What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: `T < P` ?? The code compares pointers not characters

Comment: First thing you should do is to add a few newlines, as that will make the code easier to read and understand. It will also help with the second thing: Stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger, while monitoring all variables and their values.

Comment: Good news: on your computer there's a tool called "debugger". You can use it to execute the shown program, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables and all pointers at each step; and in this manner, understand exactly how the shown code works, and why. Your debugger will be able to answer this question for you, and you should learn how to use it. Knowing how to use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: The reason you get `TT` is because those are values pointed by `t1` and `t2` after the loop is finished. You however are analysing only 1st iteration.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In this case a debugger would be unlikely to help unless one is already aware of the problem. It really depends on how the debugger does `char*` inspection - chances are it will show you a string, which is not really helpful in becoming aware of the problem. It may still help, but ultimately realizing the error in thinking requires more than just stepping through the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are doing `t1 < t2` you are not comparing `(*t1) < (*t2)` which will mean comparing `'T' < 'P'`.

Instead, it is comparing the values of memory address in which character `'T'` and `'P'` are stored. And in this case, `'T'` is stored before `'P'`.

I have included how the pointers would move throughout the loop. This should clarify the whole iteration of `while` loop.

```
E  T  E  R  N  I  T  T  P  L  A  T  E  N  E  -  O  G  -  T  A  K  P  A  P  P  E  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
^                                                                                ^
t1                                                                               t2

E  T  E  R  N  I  T  T  P  L  A  T  E  N  E  -  O  G  -  T  A  K  P  A  P  P  E  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
   ^                                                                    ^
   t1                                                                   t2

E  T  E  R  N  I  T  T  P  L  A  T  E  N  E  -  O  G  -  T  A  K  P  A  P  P  E  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
      ^                                                        ^
      t1                                                       t2

E  T  E  R  N  I  T  T  P  L  A  T  E  N  E  -  O  G  -  T  A  K  P  A  P  P  E  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
         ^                                            ^
         t1                                           t2

E  T  E  R  N  I  T  T  P  L  A  T  E  N  E  -  O  G  -  T  A  K  P  A  P  P  E  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
            ^                                ^
            t1                               t2

E  T  E  R  N  I  T  T  P  L  A  T  E  N  E  -  O  G  -  T  A  K  P  A  P  P  E  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
               ^                    ^
               t1                   t2

E  T  E  R  N  I  T  T  P  L  A  T  E  N  E  -  O  G  -  T  A  K  P  A  P  P  E  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
                  ^        ^
                  t1       t2

E  T  E  R  N  I  T  T  P  L  A  T  E  N  E  -  O  G  -  T  A  K  P  A  P  P  E  N
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
                  ^  ^
                  t2 t1
```

Comment: @KillzoneKid It's the wrong characters but the reasoning is the same.

Comment: @Shubham i guess you could add my code to your answer and i can just remove my answer down there since you actually wrote my output in your answer ahahah

Comment: @Barnack I don't think we need to merge the answers. And I am sorry if you think the output of your code matches with my answer but at the time I was writing this answer, I didn't look at your code. There was a comment in my answer (by KillzoneKid) which pointed out that my answer needed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to understand what is happening:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char txt[] = "ETERNITTPLATENE-OG-TAKPAPPEN-BLE-KASTET";
int length = strlen(txt);//

void show_position(char* t1, char* t2)//
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
        if (t1 - txt == i)
            {
            if (t2 - txt == i)
                {cout << 'X';}
            cout << '1';
            }
        else if (t2 - txt == i)
            {cout << '2';}
        else
            {cout << '-';}
        }
    cout << endl;
    }

void funk(char* t1, char* t2, int n)
    {
    show_position(t1, t2);//
    while (t1 < t2) 
        { 
        ++t1; 
        t2 -= n; 
        show_position(t1, t2);//
        } 
    cout << *t1 << *t2 << endl;
    }

int main() {
    cout << txt << endl;//
    funk(txt, txt + 27, 3);
    return 0;
    }
```

The lines followed by a // and the function declaration are there for drawing only, the rest is your almost untouched code.

A few nickpicks/suggestions (which i changed in your code):

1) use `cout << endl;` instead of `cout << "\n";`. endl is standard, and thus it will work properly in any platform (windows, linux, mac - which is linux but uses a different newline). Many apps support \n as default even on platform which don't officially use them (for example notepad++ supports the linux newline standard on windows), but that's not a good reason to not use endl.

2) If you have a function which purpose is printing something which clearly needs a newline, why you put the newline after the call instead of putting it directly inside your printing function?

Comment: do you really wanna debug like this? Its more than the double of original program.

Comment: @JeJo it always makes me laugh when people comments without reading what they're answering to. The program is the exact OP code (with some endl instead of "\n"). All i did is adding a function to print the situation on screen. Visualizing what happens helps, expecially if someone's new. And that's what the function does, it prints the situation step by step. It does what Shubham wrote after he edited his answer.

Comment: your *show_position()* is completely unnecessary. That's what I meant. You don't need to draw complete picture with symbols to understand this program.  *cout << *t1 << *t2 << endl;* this must be good enough. However, if you have a good IDE(MSVS best in my opinion), you can even go through the memory location and find what exactly the code does(in short a good debugger). What you doing is simply a lot for this simple code.

Comment: Man i dont think his teacher even mentioned what debuggers are seen his question. One should speak to someone else in a way he can understand, not pretending him to understand how other tools work in order to understand why his simple code is behaving a certain way.
Also check Shubham's answer @JeJo, he typed exactly the output of my function, and that actually helps the OP to understand whats going on.